# What's faster? file_put_contents(); fopen(); fwrite(); fclose();?

Tags: php, file-io

What is better? I have my own MySQL log so it has about 90MB, but I'm not sure which one should I use. It opens file EVERYTIME there is query to execute.

What's faster?

Comment: Run your own benchmarks. I'm sure it doesn't take hours to open a 90 MB file.

Comment: it doesn't. That's the problem, I'm on shared host and it is in production so I can't just "test" it.

Comment: You can test on your local development machine.

Comment: Premature micro-optimization is mostly a waste of time. Unless you have a performance problem, you shouldn't care. And if you have a performance problem, changing `fopen` to `file_put_contents` (or vice-versa) probably isn't going to make it any better.

Comment: microtime!  it would take you less time to write a test than to write a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100109103851/http://balancedbraces.com/2008/06/12/fopen-fwrite-fclose-vs-file_put_contents/), the `fwrite()` is a smidgen faster. *(Link to Wayback Machine, because site no longer exists.)*

My guess is that `file_put_contents()` is just a wrapper around those three methods anyways, so you would lose the overhead.

**EDIT** : [This site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) has the same information.

Comment: -1   How can this be even an answer just refering to a site which no longer exists - you could have quoted the site or reference articles from it - downvote

Comment: Er, the site existed a year ago. I should probably change that to something more recent.

Comment: The original article can still be seen on the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20100109103851/http://balancedbraces.com/2008/06/12/fopen-fwrite-fclose-vs-file_put_contents/

Comment: If you read the old article carefully the: `fwrite()` is only faster if you append data to same file, since you don't need to `fopen` and `fclose` each iteration, which is what: `file_put_contents()` does.

Comment: an important thing is `file_put_contents` when writing a file waits until the file is unlocked then performs the write and returns the number of bytes written. this is important when you have multiple processes trying to write to the same file, like `file_put_contents( "my-file.txt", $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );`

Answer (score 30):

This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

Check the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Shaun

Comment: http://www.php.net/downloads.php you could also grab the source to get the nitty gritty under the hood, should help answer these types of questions.

Comment: I looked into the source some more, it looks like fwrite directly uses php_stream_write from streams.c, so long as you aren't using any of the zend features the call to file_put_contents will also ultimately (after doing a few checks for Zend flags) call php_stream_write, like others have stated testing this (even if not in production but on a test box) is the best way to answer the question and will vary for particular scenarios.

Answer (score 12):

Depends on your use-case. I've opened files which were over .5 GB, and I certainly didn't want to use file() or file_get_contents(); And file_put_contents couldn't work because I needed to read the file too.

If you're really just interested in appending a file without reading, it doesn't terribly matter; if you're trying to read a whole file into memory (or write a whole file from memory), it similarly does not really matter -- the speed gain, as near as I've seen, is round-off error.

BUT, if you're expecting that these files will ever grow to gargantuan beasts, or if you only need a small subset of the number of lines of a given file, I cannot suggest use of fopen (or the `SplFileObject`, which is AWESOME) strongly enough -- it is really easy to read from the middle of a file with these.

---

Since you're just logging, on the other hand, I, personally, find it clearer and more concise to simply use file_put_contents with the append flag. It lets everyone know what's going on without having to look twice.

Comment: okay, thank you. Howver I'm just writing with my script

Comment: @genesis. Sorry, I'm having issues with my work machine today (May have something to do with a massive SVN checkout going on, but whatever), and I couldn't get that addendum in before you saw it.

Answer (score 10):

1. If there is only one write-operation for one file in a request, file_put_contents is better than fwrite, because it has wrappered open, write and close functions, and as fast as fwrite.
2. If there are multi-write for one file in a request, we need open file first, then write multi-times, so fwrite is faster. But, if it is a very busy system, which has a lot of "open files"(ulimit -a | grep "open files"), file_put_contents will be a more reasonable choose, because it keep the file handler shorter than fwrite.

Answer (score 8):

As per usual, have you benchmarked it? file_put_contents is essentially just a wrapper around the 3 `f*()` calls anyways, so at most you're losing out by doing one extra function call, but gaining somewhat by having less front-end code to parse.