# Json write to Database or File

Tags: php, json, file

I have the following JSON Code:

```
{"id":"datalog_transmission","firmwareType":"SenlabH","measures":[{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771395867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771395867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771575867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771575867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771755867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771755867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771935867,"value":20.5625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771935867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565772115867,"value":20.625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565772115867,"value":59},{"id":"battery_current_level","timestamp":1565772205867,"value":93}],"parameters":[],"events":[]}
```

I want to write each entry in a file:

Timestamp, Temperature, Humidity

Timestamp, Temperature, Humidity

Timestamp, Temperature, Humidity

Timestamp, Temperature, Humidity

Timestamp, Temperature, Humidity

i tried the following:

```
$yummy=(json_decode ($response));
foreach ($yummy->measures as $optie ) {

             $DATE1= $optie->timestamp;
            if ($optie->id === "temperature"){
               $TEMP1 =  . $optie->value;

             }

            if ($optie->id === "humidity"){
                $HUM1 = $optie->value;
             }
            echo "NEW VALUE-----------------<br><br>";



file_put_contents('pusherlog1.txt',$DATE1, $TEMP1." Grad Celsius ". $HUM1." Prozent Luftfeuchte . "\r\n" , FILE_APPEND);
```

but the result is:

```
1565772267194
TEMP = 20.5
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772267194
HUM = 59
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772447194
TEMP = 20.5
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772447194
HUM = 59
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772627194
TEMP = 20.5
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772627194
HUM = 59
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772807194
TEMP = 20.5625
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772807194
HUM = 59
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772987194
TEMP = 20.625
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565772987194
HUM = 59
NEW VALUE-----------------

1565773077194
NEW VALUE-----------------
```

later I would like to write the values in a database

```
$sql="INSERT INTO lorawan_stadtgraz(DATE, TEMP, HUM) VALUES('$DATE1','$TEMP1', '$HUM1')";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some basic error in your code resolved the error and replace `file_put_contents` with file IO function and everything is working fine. Check below code

```
<?php
$respo = '{"id":"datalog_transmission","firmwareType":"SenlabH","measures":[{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771395867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771395867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771575867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771575867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771755867,"value":20.5},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771755867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565771935867,"value":20.5625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565771935867,"value":59},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565772115867,"value":20.625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565772115867,"value":59},{"id":"battery_current_level","timestamp":1565772205867,"value":93}],"parameters":[],"events":[]}';

$yummy=(json_decode ($respo));
$fp = fopen("pusherlog1.txt","wb");
foreach ($yummy->measures as $optie ) {
            $TEMP1 = "";
            $DATE1 = "";
             $HUM1 = "";
            $DATE1 = $optie->timestamp;
            if ($optie->id === "temperature")
            {
               $TEMP1 =  $optie->value;
            }

            if ($optie->id === "humidity")
            {
                $HUM1 = $optie->value;
            }
            echo "NEW VALUE-----------------<br><br>";
            $string = $DATE1.", ".$TEMP1." Grad Celsius ".$HUM1."Prozent Luftfeuchte.\n";
            fwrite($fp, $string);

}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Reason to you `fwrite` over `file_put_contents` is `fwrite` is faster as compare to `file_put_contents` you can take referance from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415958/whats-faster-file-put-contents-fopen-fwrite-fclose)

Comment: 1565773970024, 20.5 Grad Celsius Prozent Luftfeuchte.

1565773970024,  Grad Celsius 59Prozent Luftfeuchte.

1565774150024, 20.5 Grad Celsius Prozent Luftfeuchte.

1565774150024,  Grad Celsius 59Prozent Luftfeuchte.

1565774330024, 20.5 Grad Celsius Prozent Luftfeuchte.

.....

Is it possible to write Date, HUM and TEMP in one line? it is easier for the next step to write every line in my mysql database

Comment: The problem now is that once the value of the temperature is and once the humidity. But not together

Comment: instead of text file you can create CSV and put your data in CSV file. CSV manage different column for each index

Comment: Also, instead of putting values in a file you can directly insert it into your table

Comment: thank you

at the moment the file input is:
1565774347645, 20.5 Grad Celsius X Prozent Luftfeuchte.
1565774347645,  X Grad Celsius 59Prozent Luftfeuchte. **and so on. every second value is left out**